# remove multiple rows from a array in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
array([
    ['192', '895'],
    ['14', '269'],
    ['1', '23'],
    ['1', '23'],
    ['50', '322'],
    ['19', '121'],
    ['17', '112'],
    ['12', '72'],
    ['2', '17'],
    ['5,250', '36,410'],
    ['2,546', '17,610'],
    ['882', '6,085'],
    ['571', '3,659'],
    ['500', '3,818'],
    ['458', '3,103'],
    ['151', '1,150'],
    ['45', '319'],
    ['44', '335'],
    ['30', '184']
])
```

How can I remove some of the rows and left the array like:

```
Table3=array([
    ['192', '895'],
    ['14', '269'],
    ['1', '23'],
    ['50', '322'],
    ['17', '112'],
    ['12', '72'],
    ['2', '17'],
    ['5,250', '36,410'],
    ['882', '6,085'],
    ['571', '3,659'],
    ['500', '3,818'],
    ['458', '3,103'],
    ['45', '319'],
    ['44', '335'],
    ['30', '184']
])
```

I removed the index 2,4,6. I am not sure how should I do it. I have tried few ways, but still can't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you actually deleted indices 2, 5, and 10 (not 2, 4 and 6). To do this you can use [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), pass it a list of the indices you want to delete, and apply it along `axis=0`:

```
Table3 = np.delete(arr, [[2,5,10]], axis=0)

>>> Table3
array([['192', '895'],
       ['14', '269'],
       ['1', '23'],
       ['50', '322'],
       ['17', '112'],
       ['12', '72'],
       ['2', '17'],
       ['5,250', '36,410'],
       ['882', '6,085'],
       ['571', '3,659'],
       ['500', '3,818'],
       ['458', '3,103'],
       ['151', '1,150'],
       ['45', '319'],
       ['44', '335'],
       ['30', '184']],
      dtype='<U6')
```